# how to interpolate string containing capture-group parentheses as regex in Raku?

Tags: regex, regex-group, raku

I want to match against a programmatically-constructed regex, containing a number of `(.*)` capture groups. I have this regex as a string, say

```
my $rx = "(.*)a(.*)b(.*)"
```

I would like to interpolate that string as a regex and match for it. The [docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regex_interpolation) tell me `<$rx>` should do the trick (i.e. interpolate that string as a regex), but it doesn't. Compare the output of a match (in the `perl6` REPL):

```
> 'xaybz' ~~ rx/<$rx>/
｢xaybz｣
```

vs the expected/desired output, setting apart the capture groups:

```
> 'xaybz' ~~ rx/(.*)a(.*)b(.*)/
｢xaybz｣
 0 => ｢x｣
 1 => ｢y｣
 2 => ｢z｣
```

---

**Comments**

One unappealing way I can do this is to [EVAL](https://docs.raku.org/routine/EVAL) my regex match (also in the REPL):

```
> use MONKEY; EVAL "'xaybz' ~~ rx/$rx/";
｢xaybz｣
 0 => ｢x｣
 1 => ｢y｣
 2 => ｢z｣
```

So while this does give me *a* solution, I'm sure there's a string-interpolation trick I'm missing that would obviate the need to rely on `EVAL`..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The result of doing the match is being matched when going outside the regex. This will work:

```
my $rx = '(.*)a(.*)b(.*)';
'xaybz' ~~ rx/$<result>=<$rx>/;
say $<result>;
# OUTPUT: «｢xaybz｣␤ 0 => ｢x｣␤ 1 => ｢y｣␤ 2 => ｢z｣␤»
```

Since, by assigning to a Match variable, you're accessing the raw Match, which you can then print. The problem is that <$rx> is, actually, a Match, not a String. So what you're doing is a Regex that matches a Match. Possibly the Match is stringified, and then matched. Which is the closest I can be to explaining the result

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't think I really understand what happened there. Could you please point me to where this is documented?

Comment: What confuses me is that "stringification" does not seem to be what's happening. Note the quotation marks `｢ ｣` around the result I get. If I stringify the match with `$/.Str` those are gone. So my getting `｢xaybz｣` cannot be due to "stringification", as that's still a Match object. The problem seems to be that the capturing parentheses are ignored in my initial attempt, and I don't see why that is.

Comment: @grobber that's right. It's simply being converted into a different Match object. I'll edit a bit to try and explain what's going on. Essentially, `<$rx>` is a Match, and you're matching to a Match, which is stringified...

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that things in `<…>` don't capture in general.

```raku
'xaybz' ~~ / <:Ll> <:Ll> <:Ll> /
# ｢xay｣
```

They do capture if the first thing after `<` is an alphabetic.

```raku
my regex foo { (.*)a(.*)b(.*) }

'xaybz' ~~ / <foo> /;
# ｢xaybza｣
#  foo => ｢xaybza｣
#   0 => ｢x｣
#   1 => ｢y｣
#   2 => ｢za｣
```

That also applies if you use `<a=…>`

```raku
'xaybz' ~~ / <rx=$rx> /;
# ｢xaybza｣
#  rx => ｢xaybza｣
#   0 => ｢x｣
#   1 => ｢y｣
#   2 => ｢za｣
```

Of course you can assign it on the outside as well.

```raku
'xaybz' ~~ / $<rx> = <$rx> /;
# ｢xaybza｣
#  rx => ｢xaybza｣
#   0 => ｢x｣
#   1 => ｢y｣
#   2 => ｢za｣

'xaybz' ~~ / $0 = <$rx> /;
# ｢xaybza｣
#  0 => ｢xaybza｣
#   0 => ｢x｣
#   1 => ｢y｣
#   2 => ｢za｣
```

---

Note that `<…>` is a sub-match, so the `$0`,`$1`,`$2` from the `$rx` will never be on the top-level.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. The bit about non-alphabetic `<>` in particular was illuminating. Note that the issue propagates: if I first do `my $rx='(\d)'; my regex R { <$rx> }; '12' ~~ /<R>/` it still doesn't capture.

Comment: grobber: that's because you defined `R` as `<$rx>`.  If you do `regex R { <rx=$rx> }` then it will work.  One of the reasons for requiring the naming is that positional captures are counted at a compile time.  If you do `regex R { <$rx> (.) }` it will be impossible to know what the number for `(.)` should be.  Named captures don't suffer from the same limitation.

Comment: "Note that the issue propagates". I'm struck by your choice of the word *issue*. The fact that only `<...>` assertions that start with an alphabetic character capture is a deliberate feature. In your example... ah, @user0721090601 has covered that. :)

Comment: @raiph: only an "issue" from my previously-uninformed perspective. Thank you both (yourself and @user0721090601): the motivation for requiring named `<>` is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to expose the inner regex result to an outside variable:

```
my $rx = "(.*)a(.*)b(.*)";
my $result;

'xaybz' ~~ / $<result>=<$rx> {$result = $<result>}/;

say $result;

# OUTPUT:

# ｢xaybz｣
# 0 => ｢x｣
# 1 => ｢y｣
# 2 => ｢z｣
```